# Getting available ports into a vector for use in a For loop

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, serial-port

EDIT: thanks to Scheff and everyone else who commented

I am currently attempting to communicate with a serial device and have to change a foreach loop into a range based for loop. In order to do this I have written the following code:

```
    std::vector<QSerialPortInfo> serialList;

    for (QSerialPortInfo const &serialPortInfo : serialList)
    {
        qDebug() << "check/n";
        if (serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier () && serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier ())
        {
            if (serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier () == trackerVendorID &&
                    serialPortInfo.productIdentifier () == trackerProductID)
            {
                trackerPortName = serialPortInfo.portName ();
                trackerIsAvailable = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this just generates an empty vector so the for loop is never used and the qDebug "check" is never called. I know I need to put something in with QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts() but I can't for the life of me work out how.

Comment: Range-based `for` loop or `std::for_each` or any other loop iterating over `serialList` (or any other container) doesn't really matter if the container is empty. You need to add elements to the container *first*.

Comment: What is the question here? The loop looks fine. Are you trying to get a list of available ports? If so, please change the question and show relevant code.

Comment: If the loop is fine then I guess the question is how do I get the available ports into a vector so I can use the loop. I'll change the question.

Comment: how did you get the availablePorts before using a range based loop? I dont see how the range based loop is relevant for your problem, wether you use that or `foreach` you need to get the available Ports somehow

Comment: `QList<QSerialPortInfo> serialList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();`? _how do I get the available ports into a vector_ `std::vector<QSerialPortInfo> serialList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts().toVector().toStdVector();` Btw. why not the range `for` loop with the `QList<QSerialPortInfo>`?

Comment: Thank you very much Scheff, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
std::vector<QSerialPortInfo> serialList;
```

But `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()` does not return a `std::vector`, it returns a `QList<QSerialPortInfo>`, which you can use as is in the for loop:

```
QList<QSerialPortInfo> serialList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

for (const QSerialPortInfo& serialPortInfo : serialList)
{
...
```